# Adjust master volume - Keep volume for all devices the same

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a USB headset and speakers on my PC, these are recognized as different devices and sound outputs in Windows 7.

I have to adjust the volume of these individually, but I would prefer to have one master volume control. This would mean that volume level of the speakers and the headset would always be the same, even when changed.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on the Volume controller.

You can see the Mixer option. 
Click on Mixer Option Set your Headphone to top most Maximum Volume and Drag your Device Speaker volume to maximum. Make sure both are in same level.

Once again when you click on the Volume controller in Taskbar It equally controls to manage the volume of all device at a time which ever the device you set to same level in Mixer Option.